# 'str' object does not support item assignment python

Tags: python, string, variable-assignment

```
XP = 0
nmin = 50
nmax = 2000

        getxp = []
        f = open("users/" + user.name.lower() + ".txt", 'r')
        xpg = f.readline().split("X Points = ",1)[1]
        f.close


elif used_prefix and cmd == "dailychance" or "dc":
                if self.getAccess(user) >=1:
                    ngnum = str(random.randrange(nmin,nmax))
                    getxp
                    XP += ngnum
                    room.message("Old XP = " + xpg[0])
                    xpg[1] = XP
                    room.message("New XP = " + xpg[1])
                    f.writeline(xpg[1])
                    XP = 0
                else:
                    room.message("You are not Whitelisted. >=( ")
```

I want it to get a random number between those min and max and then assign the number to ngnum then add ngnum to XP then send a message Old Xp = The old value then change the value to the new one then send the message New XP = new value then rewrite the old value to the new one.

Comment: `xpg` is a string (`xpg = f.readline().split("X Points = ",1)[1]`) and strings are immutable in Python - therefore it fails on `xpg[1] = XP`. Can you show us what is the input (the file) and expected output?

Comment: It would help if your code was syntactically correct (e.g. indentation) and could be run.

Comment: input file = <First line> X Points = 0 <Second Line> Nickname = Xei

Comment: @freakish Output file = X points = <old value + new value> how can i make it work? and can you suggest any good python tutotials?

Answer (score 1):

@freakish has figured out the problem that causes your error. But there are other problems, too:

```
if cmd == "dailychance" or "dc":
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to

```
if (cmd == "dailychance") or "dc":
```

and will therefore always evaluate to a true value.

Use

```
if cmd in ("dailychance", "dc"):
```

instead.

Also, you need to *call* the `.close` method: `f.close()` (note the parentheses).

Comment: That's not true: `xpg[1] = XP` while `xpg = f.readline().split("X Points = ",1)[1]` is a string. That's the cause.

Comment: @freakish: Ah, there we are. See, that's why I wrote "that I can see". You should write this as an answer.

Comment: No problem. I could write it as answer, however I would also like to know what exactly he is trying to achieve (i.e. input and output) so perhaps there's a better way to do it. The code is messy.

Comment: That's certainly true :)

Comment: trying to achieve output as New Xp = the value of xpg + the value of ngnum and it would write it in the file